# How to make a chart/shape free-floating vertically, but not horizontally

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to use the xlfreefloating function but only to position a graph in one direction but not the other? I have a macro that positions my graph between a certain range of cells. I  want it to stay freefloating for the y direction but not the x-direction. So if the graph is to the right of some data cells, and I adjust the cells and make them longer in the x direction, I want the graph to follow. But if I adjust them in the y direction, I want them to stay the same. Thanks!

Comment: The move and size with cells option is all or nothing.

Comment: Your best bet is to simply position the chart in the desired location *after* you have manipulated the cells. There is no way (or certainly no elementary/easy way, it might be done with event-handlers) to replicate the move-and-size, but limit it to one dimension. Also for clarification: `xlFreeFloating` isn't "function", it's a value assigned to the chartobject's `.Placement` property.

Comment: So in my code I have two functions (thank you for clarifying by the way, I get confused sometimes I'm pretty new to VBA): one that draws the graphs and positions them, and one that manipulates the cells. The cell manipulation obviously is run after the graphing function, but is it possible to call the graphs created in the graphing function and position them? I'll show you my  code in edits to my initial question, thank you! Also, David you're answering all my questions you really know your stuff don't you?

Comment: Actually David you have seen my code in another question that I had asked earlier, you had told me to insert `xlFreeFloating` into my code. I'm thinking I can do this, please correct me if I'm wrong: After my graphs are created, can I select the graphs on the sheet, and then just do a "move left 3 columns" type thing?

Comment: Update: when I try to select my graph, it won't let me. It tells me that I need an object or there is no chart with the specified name even though I'm using the defined chart and it's title name. When I record a macro and I select the chart, I found out my chart is named "Chart 7". Is there any way to find out the chart's name without the record macro and selecting the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this myself:

One way to do this is to manually activate the chart AFTER the cells are manipulate, and then position it in terms of left or right wherever you want it. The following code was used after my charts were created, positioned, and cells were manipulated:

```
Sub MoveCharts()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
With ActiveChart.Parent
.Left = Range("N2").Left
End With

End Sub
```